# Insert component instance into DOM

Tags: javascript, angular

I am making a select-box (select + options).

In the select component I have a list of option component instances :

```
@ContentChildren(forwardRef(() => SelectOptionComponent)) private options: QueryList<SelectOptionComponent>;
```

Also I know which one option is selected so I have a

```
private selectedOption: SelectOptionComponent;
```

attribute. Now I would like to display the selected option into the select-box main top frame (what remains of the select box when it's option list is closed). As I want to display any content and not only text, I would like to "copy" the option dom node and insert that into the main frame.

I tried several approaches without any success but I have the feeling that should be possible. Any clue ?

Comment: [Something like that ?](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)

Comment: @trichetriche Yes, but using an existing component instance instead of instantiating a new one. I've already use that method elsewhere by the way.

Comment: You could play on its position and container overflown properties, like [material selects](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview) do

Comment: That is a good idea but I want to be sure there is no clean alternative before doing that

Comment: Well you have several solutions, such as using [injectors](https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection) to get the component instance, you can also use your `@ContentChildren` to get it, but in every way, you will have to copy that instance a second time to display it (unless you move it, as proposed earlier)

Answer (score 1):

I'm just sort of thinking aloud, but:

1. Inject [`ElementRef`](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef) into the `SelectOptionComponent` and make it public.
2. Inject `ElementRef` into your select component.
3. Add a setter function to `selectedOption` in the select component that, when triggered, does `selectedOption.el.nativeElement. // gets dom node` and copies it to  wherever you want it copied to in the select component's dom (using the `ElementRef` of the select component).

i.e.

```
private _selectedOption: SelectedOptionComponent;

set selectedOption(option: SelectedOptionComponent) {
  this._selectedOption = option;

  // do other stuff as needed
  // e.g:
  // this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('').appendChild(option.el.nativeElement)
}
```

Obviously, this won't be Angular Universal / SSR friendly. Personally, I wouldn't touch the dom directly. Instead I might use the [angular renderer](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) to insert the component in the dom. Or, more likely, I'd simply use `ngIf` to toggle a special "selected" component / view.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying a solution with Renderer2, I'll let you know the result. I think I tried it before but I couldn't clone the element.

Answer (score 0):

```
export class SelectOptionComponent {
    constructor(public elt: ElementRef) { }
```

Then

```
export class SelectBoxComponent {
@ViewChild('label', {read: ElementRef}) labelNode: ElementRef;
private selectedOption: SelectOptionComponent;

constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}
...

private updateLabel() {
    Array.from(this.labelNode.nativeElement.children).forEach(child => {
        this.renderer.removeChild(this.labelNode.nativeElement, child);
    });
    if (this.selectedOption) {
        let cloned = this.selectedOption.elt.nativeElement.cloneNode(true);
        this.renderer.appendChild(this.labelNode.nativeElement, cloned);
    }
}
```